# How to test Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Comfortable Mexican Sofa CMS. I have installed it and created few snippets and few pages.

I am now interested how this I can test on local machine so I could see how the content of the page looks like? How can see the page with the snippets loaded?

When I click on a link to a page that I have created, it just says:

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hm, well, I had to define a sub page for my initial starting page, as my global page was pointing to localhost, and when I go to localhost, I got redirected to admin area or to the error noted above.

I have created a child page, and I have set slug to , for example - my-example, and then when I went to `localhost:3000/my-example` it all worked :)

Comment: @elenasys You have edited my answer just to add two spaces between `localhost:3000/my-example` and the `it`. But why?